# Unable to record sound with RecordMyDdesktop

Tags: 12.04, sound, recordmydesktop

I'm unable to record sound using this application. The check box is checked for the sound, It just doesn't record sound. I don't know what to do.

I have Ubuntu 12.04 64bit.

And Nvidia drivers don't work what so ever. So I'm just using the default Ubuntu drivers.

I looked up the site for this application. But they don't give any instructions on sound for this program.

The microphone sound input works with it. But it cant record system sounds.

Comment: The nvidia driver issue is one you should open in a new question, we try to answer one question or one question and directly related questions from the same asker in one question thread.

Answer (score 10):

I'd suggest using Kazam, it worked on first try, and you can also easily select 2 sound sources for recording. I had also huge problems with recordmydesktop, to also record my sound.

Comment: Excellent application, worked right away on Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: +1 I wish i could found this answer before wasting 4 hours with record my desktop. Kazam is great, Thanks.

Comment: Just 1 question though can it also record audio of the other person on skype call, it seems not working for me.

Comment: @HimanshuBhandari also not working for me to record audio in zoom/googlemeet voice call

Comment: May be it require PulseAudio as mentioned [below](https://askubuntu.com/a/278524/22308)

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you Kazam Screencaster for recording your screen and Pulse Audio which is sound server which allows you to do various operation on the sound passes to your hardware.

So install Kazam by following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kazam-team/unstable-series
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kazam
```

And PulseAudio by following commands

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
```

And then select Pulse Audio in Kazam Screencaster to recored system sound with recording.

Comment: Installing Pulse Audio helps me to have the sound recorded now. But I don't have to do this > select Pulse Audio in Kazam Screencaster

Comment: It turned out that PulseAudio help to hear the recorded sound when playback. Before installed, my record mp4 files have no sound.

Answer (score 3):

Once you've activated the pulse audio control go into the recording tab and with recordmydesktop recording (you'll see ALSA plug-in [recordmydesktop]: ALSA Capture from 'Internal Audio Analog Stereo'
Change this setting to  'Monitor of Internal Audio Analog Stereo' and you should see the VU control become active.

Comment: A screenshot would make this answer perfect!

Answer (score 2):

In settings->Sound
There should be a input tab please ensure that the volume for Mic is 100% then it should work properly for you (you can test if your mic is working, if you see any activity in 'input level:')

regards

Answer (score 0):

If you have Pulse and since you have Ubuntu you probably do, then you have to install the PulseAudio Volume Control with the command

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

While recordmydesktop is recording, you have to go into Pavucontrol and in the recording tab you will have to change the output to your speakers. If you don't do it while recordmydesktop is recording then it won't show up in that tab. So it's pretty important that you do it at that time.